# Non-convex and non-concave monotone functions

Tags: calculus, logarithms, convex-analysis, special-functions, monotone-functions

Is there any function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying the following conditions?:

(1) the sequence $f(n)$ is convergent;

(2) $\log f$ is eventually monotone (i.e., it is monotone from a number on);

(3) $\log f$ is not eventually convex or concave.

If yes, is there a (big) class of such functions (with various properties)?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of such functions. Let g be a positive increasing function on $\mathbb R^{+}$ such that g(n)=1-1/n for each n and such that g does not have a left derivative at some point in (k,k+1) for each k. Let $f=e^{g}$. Then $log f$ is not concave or convex eventually because convex and concave functions have left derivatives at every point. Of course, one can use right derivatives instead of left derivatives.

Comment: Thanks, could you please give an explicit example of this class of functions.